# How to ask about the purpose behind a queue in public?

Tags: phrase-request

Recently I was wondering which queue to join in a public place. So how one should ask the last person about this?

Comment: Is this the queue for XXX?

Comment: I'm eternally grateful to Kate Fox in *Watching the English* for calling my attention to [this quote from George Mikes:](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/george_mikes_133330) *An Englishman, even if he is alone, forms **an orderly queue of one.***

Comment: "Which queue should I join?"

Comment: I suspect there may be cultural differences.  Americans would probably not say queue for example, but line.

Comment: Americans would just about never use the word "queue". In AmE, an example sentence is: "Is this the line for the bathroom?"