# Are there priority lines in America or Europe?

Tags: word-request

In Brazil,  we have a line in places like banks and supermarket specifically for old people, pregnant women and disabled people which is usually faster than a regular line. We call that a preferential line. Is there such a thing in America or Europe? If so, what do you call it?

Would you know what I mean by preferential/priority line?

Comment: In Britain we call them _queues_, not _lines_. I don't remember seeing one, but we would probably call it a priority _service point_ or (in a supermarket) _checkout_.

Comment: They existed during the Covid-19 lockdown in some supermarkets, for the elderly and often for National Health Service workers, but, in general in Britain everyone takes their turn, often insisting on it.

Comment: I thought only Brits were capable of queuing anyway. Especially the English. [*An Englishman, even if he is alone, forms an orderly queue of one.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/302845/how-to-ask-about-the-purpose-behind-a-queue-in-public#comment566022_302845)

Comment: Canada does not have special lines anywhere for the elderly/pregnant/disabled/... If we did, they would likely be called something like "preferential line". Since we're not familiar with the concept, if you want people outside Brazil to understand, consider describing it fully, like "*preferential line for the elderly, pregnant and disabled*".

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., they are most frequently called “express lanes” or “express lines,” but such things for the elderly, pregnant, or disabled are not frequent. The most common use for an express lane in a grocery store is for customers with few items to purchase.

Comment: In the UK, the old express lane "20 items or less" idea has pretty much vanished, in favour of self-checkouts, where you scan your own groceries. The old operator-tills are fewer & fewer every year now. You can even scan your groceries on your own phone as you shop, then all you have to do is pay before you leave, again by phone or NFC card. Fewer tills take cash too, most are NFC.

Answer (score 0):

Banks in the US may have preferred lanes, but they will be for business customers rather than any of the factors you named

One place you will encounter such things are airports, they will often have designated lanes for people with wheelchairs and baby strollers (sometimes for people whose children are ambulatory but young enough that the parents are still carrying diaper bags and the like). Also lanes for frequent flyers (on the assumption they know how to sort their stuff to make the job go quicker). Not sure if there is a industry-wide name for the practice. But equally calling it "express", "priority", "preferred" most any US speaker would understand the meaning.

Comment: People still go into banks in the US? I haven't been in one in 20 years. I can understand businesses that do cash transactions would go in, or use the night boxes, but regular people - unless it's to arrange a loan etc, what on earth do people still need to actually be physically present for? Most of the banks here have gone from 17 tellers with queues of people paying cheques & dealing cash in & out all day every day to 2 or 3 informal desks & a whole lot of empty space with potted plants.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. You don't need to physically go inside the bank for a simple deposit or withdrawal. But you still need to go in to apply for a loan, or to open a new account, etc. I suppose more functions are now available on line so maybe there is less and less need. And of course there are always people who just prefer to work with a human being. Or if you're having problems with the technology you may want to talk to a human being. (Personally I prefer NOT to have to talk to a human being, but that's another story.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm hard pressed to think of a place in the US where there was a special line for old people or pregnant women or whatever. During covid some stores had hours when they were only open for old people, etc. But that was the whole store and not just a special line. So we probably don't have a name for it because we don't have such a thing.

The closet thing I can think of is that most parking lots have spaces near the entrance that are marked as just for handicapped people. We call these, cleverly enough, "handicapped spaces".